# Does the number of remote requests affects performance?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, amfphp

I have a photobook making site and i'm trying to improve loading and saving performance.

The photobook making tool is displayed in a web browser, is done in Flash, and the remote calls for database operations are done through AmfPhp.

The algorithm for saving a photobook basically says:

```
foreach(page in photobook){
    foreach(component in page){
        //Make a remote call that saves the component in the Database
    }
}
```

This means that if a photobook has 30 pages, with 10 components(photos) per page, the tool will create approximately 300 simultaneous connections without counting the uploads connections.

Firefox for example, seems to all ready create a queue to process the requests.

Does this affects the performance at all?

Will it help to create a queue that controls the number of simultaneous remote calls?

Is it worth it?

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: Well you answered your own question. It affects the performance. Why don't you loop trough your pages and components and add it all to an XML file and send THAT to the server? (1 call).

Comment: What do you thing about using a JSON string instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every request to remote server will result in time increase for your script execution.

3 queries to database are faster then 3 remote requests.

So yes your performance will be heavily impacted with 300 remote requests.

Best solution is to either paginate, or serialize all of data in XML. Though careful with XML, if too big it will cause performance issue as well.

I think pagination is the best option.

Comment: @putvande also suggested this, but i have two questions. One, An XML "too big" would be a file of what size?. Two, what do you thing about using a JSON string instead?

Comment: JSON or XML? THe aswer is, which ever you find more comfortable in my opinion. I prefer XML as I mostly use XMLReader or DOM object in php. But some prefer JSON, and there is nothing wrong with that way either as both represent serialization of data.

XML too big? There is no actual file size to determine this. It's about performance. The size of XML should be determined by a remote server response speed and your script processing time. Simply put, if it is a cron or some back process script time does not matter. But if script parses content in real time, anything over few seconds is too much

Comment: The process is done in real time. I guess i'll have to do some benchmarks to see whats better for my case. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> 300 simultaneous requests

Yes. Too much.

**Only load what you need.**
Why are you loading every single picture immediately? Load the first page, and maybe pre-load the second, but you're going further than that you're using up a lot of bandwidth if the person doesn't look any further than the first page.

Further to that, let's assume your photobook allows the user to see a high-resolution version retrieved via javascript. When the use clicks this their request gets added to the bottom of the queue and is not processed until the last of the 300 other requests complete.

Comment: The loading process of the photobook does what you are suggesting. I load the photos on demand. the problem comes when i have to call remote services for database operations like saving a photobook or loading its information. Thanks for your suggestion anyway.